# K-theory as a generalized cohomology theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Which of the statements is wrong:

1. a generalized cohomology theory (on well behaved topological spaces) is determined by its values on a point
2. reduced complex $K$-theory $\tilde K$ and reduced real $K$-theory $\widetilde{KO}$ are generalized cohomology theories (on well behaved topological spaces)
3. $\tilde K(*)= \widetilde{KO} (*)=0$

But certainly $\tilde K\neq \widetilde{KO}$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1 is doubly wrong.  First, you need to distinguished generalized cohomology theories and *reduced* generalized cohomology theories.  If you want to work with the latter, you should replace "a point" in 1 by "$S^0$", and then the corrected version of 3 no longer holds.  But even this new version 1' is false; a generalized cohomology theory is not determined by its coefficients, unless they are concentrated in a single degree (example: complex K-theory vs. integer cohomology made even periodic).

Comment: Thanks, Reid. Someone should change the "Generalized cohomology theories" section in Wikipedia's article on "Cohomology". 

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Well, Wikipedia does use quotes around "determined by its values on a point" :) but I agree that this statement is misleading at best.

Comment: It could easily be fixed by putting a link to the entry for the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence as a way of making this precise.

Comment: Reid, a last thing: Why doesn't the corrected version of 3 hold? Isn't it true that $\tilde K(S^0)=\widetilde{KO}(S^0)=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: We're thinking of generalized cohomology theories as taking values in *graded* abelian groups.  Thus $\tilde{K}^q(S^0)\not\approx \tilde{KO}^*(S^0)$, for instance if $q\equiv -1,-2,-6\mod 8$.

Comment: But the statement about cohomology theories being determined by their coefficients is not totally wrong -- if you have a natural transformation $K \to L$ of homology theories which induce an isomorphism on the point (or $\mathbf{S}^0$ in the case of reduced theories), then it's an isomorphism. But you do need to have a natural transformation in the first place.